# Move the aside box about the review queues grid to the top

Tags: feature-request, review, design

With the recent changes to the review page, on a PC screen with sufficient width, the review page looks as in this example (note the "aside" box in it, containing "Super User is moderated by ...", shown to the right of the grid of review queues):

[image]

If however, you reduce the screen width a bit, at some point the layout gets changed so that it looks like so (the "aside" box is now shown above the various review queues):

[image]

IMO the last layout (with reduced width) is a much better use of the available space on the browser page. Therefor I suggest to also use that layout in case where the width is sufficient to show the aside box to the right.

Doing so would have the additional advantage to use the available white space (in front of each of the 6 most recent reviewers images) for some other sort of purpose (eg: increase the size of the images of those recent viewers with X %).